# Increasing Triplet Subsequence

Tags: java

I am working on a problem that states the following:

`Given an unsorted array return whether an increasing subsequence of length 3 exists in the array or not. Formally return true if there exists i, j, k such that:
arr[i]<arr[j]<arr[k] given 0 <= i < j < k <= n-1`

This is my code:

```
public boolean increasingTriplet(int[] nums) {
    if (nums.length < 3) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-2; i++) {
        if (nums[i] < nums[i+1]) {
            if (nums[i+1] < nums[i+2]) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

My code fails on the following input:

`[5,1,5,5,2,5,4]` Apparently my code should return true for this sequence but I cannot for the life of me figure out why since I don't see any increasing subsequences of length 3. Any help understanding this issue is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ah I see my error now. I assumed that the subsequence had to be contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean increasingTriplet(int[] nums) {
    int first=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int second=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int third=Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    for(int p=0; i<nums.length; p++){
        if(nums[p]<=third){
            third=nums[p];
        }else{
            if(nums[p]<=second){
                first=third;
                second=nums[p];
            }else{
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The whole idea behind this code is if we have found a pair of values in increasing sequence, we can only replace this pair with the new pair of increasing sequence if first value of the new pair is  smaller than the first value of the old pair and second value of the new pair is  smaller than the second value of the old pair. At the same time, we check if the number is bigger than the second which would complete the sequence(we will return `true` in this case).

Code start comparing values from third to second instead of first to second, but the idea is same as above.

Answer (score -1):

Here's one possible solution:

```
public static boolean increasingTriplet(int[] nums) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length-2; ++i) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < nums.length-1; ++j) {
            if (nums[j] > nums[i]) {
                for (int k = j+1; k < nums.length; ++k) {
                    if (nums[k] > nums[j]) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```